# Como obtener el valor de un atributo html, mediante jquery?

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cupon_check" class="cupon_check" attr-num-doc="D00001" attr-sub-tipo="2" value="12848">
```

y estoy intentando obtener el vator de `attr-sub-tipo de la siguiente forma:

```
$(".cupones_bienvenida_costarica").find(".cupon_check[attr-num-doc='" + nombre_cupon + "']:checked").each(function(index,value){
                    console.log("CUPONES BIENVENIDA");
                    console.log($(this).data("sub-tipo"));
                });
```

Lo realizo en esa forma ya que debo obtener ese valor de varios input checkbox que estén seleccionados.
pero no me funciona.

De antemano muy agradecido

Comment: Muestra el contexto donde está tu `input` para poder ayudarte mejor: ¿está en un `div`, en un `form` o dónde?  Además, dinos desde que accíon (evento) intentas obtener el atributo. Dices que debes recorrer varios `checkbox` que estén seleccionados. Dí que tienen en común esos checkbox, qué los agrupa, si una clase en específico u otra cosa.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estás usando la función `.data` de jQuery, esta funciona para extraer atributos HTML que comienzan con `"data- "`, el atributo que usas no es así, cámbialo por `.attr('attr-sub-tipo')`, esta función sirve para cualquier atributo.